# 401 unauthorized page for swagger?

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I am enable swagger2 by @EnableSwagger2. However, when I try to hit "/swagger-ui.html", it first hit my Authentication Filter. Then, I wrote the following code to bypass the authentication check

```
String resourcePath = new UrlPathHelper().getPathWithinApplication(httpRequest);
if ("/swagger-ui.html".equalsIgnoreCase(resourcePath)) {
     filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

I can see the `filterChain.doFilter(request, response);` was hit. However, when I let the debug go, it returns a page with information below

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Wed Apr 04 15:41:50 EDT 2018
There was an unexpected error (type=Unauthorized, status=401).
No message available
```

Any idea, guys?

Comment: do you need to add "/swagger-ui.html" as an exception from filtere configuration? that could be the situation with Oauth2

Comment: @GeorgiStoyanov, how can I do that? I put `security.basic.enabled = false` in the application.properties, same result.

Comment: Think you can add your own `WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`, override `configure(WebSecurity web)` method and there put   `web.ignoring().antMatchers("/swagger-ui.html")` ofc annotate that class with `@Configuration`

Comment: Thanks a lot, @GeorgiStoyanov. It works perfectly. Could you please copy your comments as an answer so that I can accept it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Think you can add your own`WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`, than override `configure(WebSecurity web)`  method and there put `web.ignoring().antMatchers("/swagger-ui.html")` ofc annotate that class with `@Configuration`

```java
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
    
        @Override
        public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
            super.configure(web);
            web.ignoring().antMatchers("swagger-ui/**", "swagger-ui**", "/v3/api-docs/**", "/v3/api-docs**");
        }
```

Answer (score 9):

I encountered the same issue in my project and discovered this solution, so first add this **config file to the project**

```
package bla.bla.conf;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class Swagger2Config {
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors
                        .basePackage("bla.bla.controllers"))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }

}
```

and then add this code block to you **WebSecurityConfig**

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().mvcMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**");
    web.ignoring().mvcMatchers("/swagger-ui.html/**", "/configuration/**", "/swagger-resources/**", "/v2/api-docs","/webjars/**");
}
```

**my problem fixed**

`source` : [swagger.io](https://swagger.io/docs/)

Comment: This worked for me, thx. Do you or does anyone know why "/swagger-ui.html/**" isn't enough?

Comment: @msTam - when you hit swagger-ui-.html , all other supported files like css, jars also gets loaded and they are also behind the security and if you dont bypass them then page will not be loaded and it will still prompt for authentication.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same error and I add this code inside the class **websecurityConfig**

```
 @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll() 
                .antMatchers("/api/test/**").permitAll() // permit the class of test
                .antMatchers("/**").permitAll() // permit all the routers after swagger-ui.html
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```

Comment: It's unclear to me whether you are saying that the added code resolved the problem, or if this answer in fact falls into an "I have this problem, too" category. If indeed your code change has resolved the OP's problem, in order to avoid having your answer downvoted, I would suggest rewording it.

Answer (score 0):

As answered by Georgi Stoyanov , adding that much code removed **Whitelabel Error Page** error but my swagger UI home page was blank as there was 401 issue in loading some css & js files. 
[Swagger-ui with Spring security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53381926/swagger-ui-with-spring-security)

Also, important point that I want to mention is that my swagger UI was working for Weblogic deployment without above code (only `HttpSecurity` override was enough ) and I was facing issue only when running app in embedded tomcat.

**Spring Boot Version : 1.5.2.RELEASE**

**SpringFox Version 2.8.0**

So I had to made code changes [as answered by me in linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53652997/3850730) to load all CSS & JS files also.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this was my solution.

if do you have a Spring security config, you must to give authorization at all urls that swagger needs

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
        .csrf()
        .disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/api/loggin").permitAll()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/swagger-resources/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/swagger-ui/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/v2/api-docs").permitAll()
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated();           
}
```

and in your class main you shuld to add this notation

```
@EnableSwagger2
```

and finally in yor pom.xml this dependencies.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

for use http://localhost:8090/swagger-ui/