# Swagger-ui with Spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, swagger, swagger-ui

I have a simple REST application with authentication service. I tried to add swagger and swagger-ui to it, but I can only see my endpoints in `/v2/api-docs`.
In `swagger-ui.html` I see only groups of endpoints but I am unable to extend any list.

In chrome debug I see:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 ()
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined

and on a terminal with a server:

> ERROR 10020 --- [nio-5001-exec-3] c.t.r.a.p.JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint    : Responding with unauthorized error. Message - Full authentication is required to access this resource

It looks like my config files are missing something, I tried few solutions I found on a web but still nothing work.

This is my code:

pom

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.2</version>
</dependency>
```

controller

```
@RestController
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER')")
@RequestMapping(path = "restaurant")
@Api(value="restaurant", description="Example operations for restaurants")
public class RestaurantController {
// endpoints
}
```

swagger bean

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.tablebooker.restaurantservice.restaurant"))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }
}
```

SecurityConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
        securedEnabled = true,
        jsr250Enabled = true,
        prePostEnabled = true
)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
//other methods

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors()
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/",
                        "/favicon.ico",
                        "/**/*.png",
                        "/**/*.gif",
                        "/**/*.svg",
                        "/**/*.jpg",
                        "/**/*.html",
                        "/**/*.css",
                        "/**/*.js")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/auth/**")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/restaurant/**")
                .hasRole("USER")
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();

        http.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/v2/api-docs", "/configuration/ui", "/swagger-resources", "/configuration/security", "/swagger-ui.html", "/webjars/**");
    }
}
```

Any ideas how can I make my configuration work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you should registry swagger's resources.

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {


    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
    }
}
```

Then cause you're using Spring Security,maybe you should shutdown privileges.

```
   @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().mvcMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**");
        // ignore swagger 
        web.ignoring().mvcMatchers("/swagger-ui.html/**", "/configuration/**", "/swagger-resources/**", "/v2/api-docs");
    }
```

And maybe it's better for you to use swagger which the version is under 2.8.0,or you may have to face to lots of bugs.

Answer (score 6):

For me, there was no issue in traditional Weblogic deployment without any mention of `@Override public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception`  ...Only `@Override protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception` was enough and UI was visible on swagger.

But the same code was not working on Apache Tomcat server so below code was needed ,

`@Override public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception { web.ignoring().mvcMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**"); // ignore swagger  web.ignoring().mvcMatchers("/swagger-ui.html/**", "/configuration/**", "/swagger-resources/**", "/v2/api-docs","/webjars/**"); }`

`/webjars/**` being missing in answer by AokoQin.

Answering here because I didn't faced any issues on Weblogic without above code but only Tomcat. I already had resources added via `ResourceHandlerRegistry` in mvc config.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers helped me, but are not quite complete / outdated. I was facing the same issue and it's working now:

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");

        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }
}
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  ...

  @Override
  public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web
      .ignoring()
        .mvcMatchers("/swagger-ui.html/**", "/configuration/**", "/swagger-resources/**", "/v2/api-docs", "/webjars/**");
  }

  ...

}
```

Comment: I've tried this, and it got me closer. Part of the swagger ui shows up, giving me the familiar green bar. But underneath, it says "401 : {"timestamp":"2021-01-15T07:09:06.524+0000","status":401,"error":"Unauthorized","message":"Full authentication is required to access this resource","path":"/NeptuneDreams/CustomerOrders/1.0.0/api-docs"} http://localhost:8080/NeptuneDreams/CustomerOrders/1.0.0/api-docs"