# Spring Security interaction with Swagger

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, swagger

I have an app backend that uses spring security and for the sake of documentations i'm using swagger.
For some reason, this configuration isn't working. It gives me a 401 when accessing anything swagger related.

This is my security config:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/v2/**", "/webjars/**", "/swagger-resources/**", "/swagger-ui.html").permitAll()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login").permitAll()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/signup").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .addFilterBefore(new UserPasswordAuthenticationFilterToJWT("/login", super.authenticationManager()), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .addFilterBefore(new UserPasswordSignUpFilterToJWT("/signup", users), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .addFilterBefore(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

and this is my swagger config:

```
@Bean
public Docket api() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com"))
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build().apiInfo(info());
}
```

What isnt working here? I can't seem to figure it out

Comment: you are using springfox, try adding "/webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/**" to antMatchers permitAll list

Comment: Check out this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53381926/swagger-ui-with-spring-security

Answer (score 0):

Try `httpSecurity.antMatchers("/swagger*").permitAll()` or `web.ignoring().antMatchers("/swagger*")`.

I have tried `"/swagger-ui.html"` but it did not work. I suppose there would be a different routing strategy of swagger2. So permit all requests possessing prefix of `"/swagger*"` may solve the problem.